# How to create a list of Guid (Guid []) from a list of objects with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code :

```
 {
        int i = 0;
        Guid[] ids = new Guid[clientCertifications.Count()];
        foreach (Certification certif in clientCertifications)
        {
            ids[i] = certif.Id;
            i++;           
        }
            return listOffices.GroupBy(lo => lo.pk_Office)
                    .Select(loG => loG.First()
                        .MapOfficeToModel(
                        loG.Where(g => g.FK_Guid.In(ids)).Select(g => g.FK_Guid).ToCertifications(clientCertifications)
                        ));
        }
```

I would like to know if it is possible to obtain the list "ids" using a select or other word of linq? In the example I use a loop for and foreach, but I think we can do shorter no? In the line :

```
loG.Where(g => g.FK_Guid.In(***here something like: clientCertifications.Select(o => o.Id ... )*** ids)).Select(g => g.FK_Guid).ToCertifications(clientCertifications)`
```

Comment: `Guid[] ids = clientCertifications.Select(certif => certif.Id).ToArray();`

Comment: `var ids = clientCertifications.Select(x => x.Id);` and then `Where(g => ids.Contains(g.FK_Guid))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of your code:

```
int i = 0;
Guid[] ids = new Guid[clientCertifications.Count()];

foreach (Certification certif in clientCertifications)
{
    ids[i] = certif.Id;
    i++;           
}
```

is basically the complicated version of:

```
var ids = clientCertifications.Select(certif => certif.Id).ToArray();
```

And you should be able to put `clientCertifications.Select(certif => certif.Id).ToArray()` wherever you would have used the variable `ids` if it's plain LinQ. If you have a provider for LinQ that does transformations (for example to database statements) that may not work and you may need the temporary variable. But then, if you do use such a provider, there might be an entirely different and maybe better way.

Comment: Wouldn't this throw an exception since the array is never initialized?

Comment: @maccettura I'm not sure what you are talking about. How would one initialize an array and why?

Comment: @maccettura Oh you mean the quoted original code? Yes, you are right, I inadvertantly fixed that bug.

Comment: @nvoigt no, I mean _your_ code.  Like Rufus said, `ids` is null, so as soon as you access by an index it with throw

Comment: @maccettura You do realize that **that's not my code, but the OPs** right? I quoted it to say **that block can be simplified**.

Comment: @nvoigt ah, OP had edited after your answer so your two code snippets were out of sync.